# What is the ether-pudding / truffle-artifactor front end?

Tags: truffle, truffle-contract, ether-pudding

I am trying to figure out how to interact with a smart contract deployed through truffle. I am looking at the truffle documentation [here](https://truffle.readthedocs.io/en/develop/getting_started/contracts/).  They are describing how to call a function in a deployed contract, and they write:

> Now let's look at the Javascript object called MetaCoin provided for us by Truffle and Ether Pudding, made available within our frontend:
>
> Print the deployed version of MetaCoin

`console.log(MetaCoin.deployed());`

> outputs:
>
> Contract
>
> - address: "0xa9f441a487754e6b27ba044a5a8eb2eec77f6b92"
> - allEvents: ()
> - getBalance: ()
> - getBalanceInEth: ()
> - sendCoin: ()

I have no idea how to recreate this, because I don't know what they mean by 'available within our frontend'. What frontend?